# read & parse POST JSON with fastcgi++ & json-spirit

Tags: jquery, c++, post, json-spirit, fastcgi++

I'm using fastcgi++ for my ajax pages, parsing and encoding with json-spirit.  (I'm also very new to c++)

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the post data.

I cut my teeth on .net & php, and those would conveniently convert a json data string (speaking in jQuery here, so my vocab is probably off) to simple variables or `$_POST` array respectively.

I'm looking at the main example for reading POST data on fastcgi++ http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/doc/2.1/a00003.html, but it only shows `it->first` and `it->second.value`.  I can't find anything in the linked docs on that page.

Since I don't have the http knowledge to articulate this properly, is there a way to read a jQuery `ajax()` `data` string, for example, `{foo: "bar", jim: "bob"}` by `foo` and `jim` in fastcgi++?

If not, should the `it->first` simply be treated as a string to be parsed by json-spirit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, OK.

First, jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> **data**
>
> Type: PlainObject or String
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to
>   the url for GET-requests.

So jQuery does break it up into a POST query string for you.

Then, fastcgi++, via the Session tutorial, there's a piece of code `environment().findPost("data").value` that apparently references the element `<input type='text' name='data' value='Hola señor, usted me almacenó en una sesión' />`.  No need to use spirit to parse incoming ajax data.

`environment()` looks like it's initialized automatically for you in `Fastcgipp::Request`.

I'm loving this framework more each day!

Now, I just need to figure out how to integrate it with websocket++...

---

How a multi-level json object will be converted into a query string and read in via fastcgi++ is probably best left to another question.